# Spring. load application.properties with sections

Tags: java, spring

I ask you for help. 
I have a file with properties:

```
[dbname1]

host= ...

port= ...

username= ...

password= ...

[dbname2]

…

[dbname3]

…

[.......]
```

There are more than 1 number of sections.
Name of DB may be any.

Can you tell me please what is better way to read properties from file with sections: to realize it with PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer or any other standart way of Spring Boot?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have sections in a properties file

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0204propertiesfileformat01.html

You can use YAMLformat instead ( it's supported by spring boot )

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml

YAML Format supports hierarchical properties definition and you can have override them per Profile in the same file